# How do I remove tutorial information in Sea of Thieves?

Tags: sea-of-thieves

I'm new to Sea of Thieves on Xbox One and on my first session online there were some handy tips telling me next steps that permanently took up a large piece of the HUD at the bottom. Some examples are telling me to propose a basic voyage at the Captain's Table or to vote on the voyage.

These messages have remained in each new play session (I'm playing Adventure mode) and they take up a large amount of screen space. Does anyone know how to get rid of these without having to complete the basic mission each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These messages should go away after you complete what they tell you to do.  Sometimes they show up again after updates and you will have to do them again to get rid of them.  There may also be an option in settings to turn these off but I am not positive.  (If there is a setting it would likely be in accessibility)